# Constant function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ non-injective?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a constant function such that $f(x) = c$, $x\in\Bbb R$ and $c\in\Bbb R$, does $f$ qualify as a real-valued function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$? Also, $f$ would be non injective, right?

I'm trying to prove that the following is false : If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a function, real numbers $a\lt b$ such that $f$ is injective in $[a,b]$ always exist.

Would using a constant function like the one in the first paragraph as a counter-example do the trick and disprove the second paragraph?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (read: $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$). This is because $\{c\}\subseteq\mathbb R$. Moreover, $f$ is non-surjective, as $\{c\}\neq\mathbb R$. Also, $f$ is non-injective, as $f(1)=f(2)$, for instance.

Comment: **What** does "surjective in $[a,b]$" mean??? ("Injective in $[a,b]$" is clear...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $c\in\Bbb R$, yes, the constant function $c$ is a real-valued function. And it is non-injective.

Your question is unclear. If the question is

> If $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$, then must there be a real-valued function with domain $\Bbb R$ which is a surjective function from $\Bbb R$ onte $[a,b]$?

Then the statement is true: if you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&(b-a)\sin(x)+\frac{a+b}2,\end{array}$$then the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$. I don't see how do you intend to use a constant function as a counter-example.

But if the question is

> Does the range of every real valued function with domain $\Bbb R$ alwyas contain an interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$?

then the answer is negative and a constant function will work as a counter-example.

And if the question is

> For every function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$, must there be $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<b$ and that $f|_{[a,b]}$ is injective?

then you're right: no, and any constant function is a counter-example.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a counterexample surjective in the open interval $(a,b)$ but not in the closed interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: @FShrike Sure: $f(x)=\frac{(b-a)x}{1+|x|}+\frac{b+a}2$.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken then, this serves as a valid counterexample for OP. They seemed to want to disprove that a function is always surjective in some closed $[a,b]$, which I believe your example is not. I think $\arctan$ is another such example

Comment: @FShrike I had not noticed how the question was ambiguous and I have edited my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Okay so it turns out I completely butchered the question because of being in a rush. I edited the post accordingly. I only need to know if a constant function is non injective and if using it as a counter example would disprove that you can always find a<b such that f is injective in [a,b]. Forget I ever mentioned the word surjective.

Comment: Yes, constant functions are a counter example to that assertion. I will edit my answer.